# How to change the font size and position of legend in ROCAUC in yellowbrick, micoro avg and macro avg. How do I make the two lines different?

Tags: python-3.x, yellowbrick

I used ROCAUC in yellowbrick. I want to change the font size and position of the legend. What should I do? Micro average and macro average appear in the same line color. Is there a way to make the two lines different?

```
from yellowbrick.classifier import ClassBalance, ROCAUC, ClassificationReport, ClassPredictionError

clf=model_sme5.fit(X_sme_train5,y_sme_train5)
rocauc = ROCAUC(clf,classes=['No DL','DL'])

rocauc.score(X_test5,y_test5)  

r = rocauc.poof()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For font size you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/47685746/2894909

As talked about in the previous stackoverflow comment above.  You can edit the plots the same way you would any matplotlib object.

You can check out the Yellowbrick FAQs for examples of this.
http://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/faq.html

Also,  you can read up on effective matplotlib and yellowbrick 
http://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/matplotlib.html