# Increase font size of title, labels and legend for Yellowbrick Parallel Coordinates Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, yellowbrick

I'm using a Parallel Coordinates plot, and I wish to increase the font size of the Axis Labels, Legend and Title, can someone help me out? Here's what I have:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from yellowbrick.features import ParallelCoordinates

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :] 
y = iris.target

features = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']
classes = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
title = "Plot over Iris Data"

# Instantiate the visualizer
visualizer = ParallelCoordinates(
    classes=classes, features=features, fast=False, alpha=.40, title=title)

# Fit the visualizer and display it
visualizer.fit_transform(X, y)
visualizer.show()
```

I saw another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450804/yellowbrick-increasing-font-size-on-yellowbrick-generated-charts) where they did this:

```
for label in viz.ax.texts:
    label.set_size(12)
```

But this does not change anything for me, and I can't seem to find an alternative that would work for the labels, title and legend.

Comment: Could you create a standalone example including the imports?   Could you add a link to "the other post"?

Comment: I've added reproducible example :) I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: Your suggestion is great for the axis values, any suggestion for the labels and the title as well? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450804/yellowbrick-increasing-font-size-on-yellowbrick-generated-charts), the matplotlib `ax` elements can be accessed directly to change their properties (color, fontsize, ...). That post also suggests replacing `visualizer.show()` by `visualizer.finalize()` (which adds a.o. the title and the legend), so the elements can be updated before showing the plot.

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from yellowbrick.features import ParallelCoordinates

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :]
y = iris.target

features = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']
classes = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
title = "Plot over Iris Data"

# Instantiate the visualizer
visualizer = ParallelCoordinates(
    classes=classes, features=features, fast=False, alpha=.40, title=title)

# Fit the visualizer and display it
visualizer.fit_transform(X, y)
visualizer.finalize()  # creates title, legend, etc.

visualizer.ax.tick_params(labelsize=22)  # change size of tick labels
visualizer.ax.title.set_fontsize(30)  # change size of title

for text in visualizer.ax.legend_.texts:  # change size of legend texts
     text.set_fontsize(20)

visualizer.fig.tight_layout()  # fit all texts nicely into the surrounding figure
visualizer.fig.show()
```

[image: increasing font sizes for yellowbrick parallel coordinates]

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I was not sure how to access the different things, this makes sense.